# Class 'NgForm' has no instance getter 'user'

Tags: angular, dart

I am trying to build a form based on angular2dart.

The component class:

```
    @Component(
        selector: 'start-app',
        directives: const[materialInputDirectives],
        styleUrls: const ['login_component.css'],
        templateUrl: 'login_component.html')
    class LoginComponent {

      String scaleImg = 'packages/wp_login/assets/scale.svg';
      Login login = new Login();

      onSubmit() {
        print('Submit');
      }

    }
```

and the template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="image">
            <img [src]="scaleImg">
        </div>
        <div class="forms">
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #login="ngForm">
                <div>
                    <material-input type="text" label="User" [(ngModel)]="login.user"></material-input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <material-input type="password" label="Password" [(ngModel)]="login.password"></material-input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <material-input type="text" label="Language" [(ngModel)]="login.language"></material-input>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I've got ther error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 #login="ngForm"
```

creates a template variable `login` that references the `NgForm` directive.

```
[(ngModel)]="login.user"
```

fails because `login` references the `#login="ngForm" template variable and the error message is right about that it doesn't have a property`user`.

You need to rename either the template variable or the property of your component.

Comment: First of all, thanks so much. I rename `#login` to `#loginCtrl`. To create an instance of Login should I do on `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Should be fine where it is. It only needs to be ni `ngOnInit()` if it depends for example on values passed to `@Input()`s